# Unabel to set date in plugin pick me up date picker,i am using angularjs1,

Tags: jquery, angularjs, pickmeup

I am using date Picker of *Pickmeup Date Picker*. I am using it in angularjs with some piece of jquery code. now i am facing issue,i am unable to set date in date from text field on loading of document. 
i set it to timeout 3 seconds, it works only when, date picker is open on page. other wise it did not set the date in date picker.

```
app.controller("SummaryController", function ($scope, PRService) {
  $("input[id$='date-to']").val("01/01/2016"); 
});
```

Points:
date picker is working fine. 
in master page,i initialize the instance of pickmeup date picker.
my concern is only about set custom date on page load.
also see the attached image for better under standing.

**img1 is document load view**

[image]

**img2 is when date picker is opened.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$scope.myDate = $filter('date')(new Date(myCustomDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

where myDate is the ng-model of the date picker.

Comment: ng-model is not accessible when we use Pickmeup date picker.

Comment: Thanks alot for reply. i fixed it by myself.
i used this code 
pickmeup('[id$="date-fromDOS"]').set_date('01/01/2016');

Comment: your solution is also worked for me. thanks again.  :)